# Question about compact resolvent and inverse operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T\colon H^2([a,b])\to L^2([a,b])$ be some linear operator.

Show that it is densely defined and has compact resolvent (i.e. $T^{-1}$ has dense range and is compact).

Hint: Use that $H^2([a,b])$ is compactly embedded in $L^2([a,b])$.

---

I do not know exactly if I got this task right: Is it meant in the sense of an equivalence, that is: it is enough to prove that $T^{-1}$ has dense range and is compact to prove that $T$ is densely defined and has compact resolvent?
Or is the statement in parantheses only an implication?

I am a bit confused.

Anyway, the given hint reminds me on [Embedding compact iff resolvent compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277853/embedding-compact-iff-resolvent-compact)

Comment: I don't think you mean $T : H^2 \rightarrow L^2$. I think you mean $T : H^2 \subset L^2 \rightarrow L^2$. Please check on that.

Comment: On my exercise sheet it is indeed written $T\colon H^2\to L^2$ but I am quite sure what is really meant is $T\colon H^2\subset L^2\to L^2$.

Comment: It's critical to distinguish between these, because the norm being used in the range depends on the underlying space. Writing $T : H^2 \rightarrow L^2$ comes with an implied $H^2$ norm on the domain, whereas $T : H^2 \subset L^2 \rightarrow L^2$ comes with an implied $L^2$ norm on the domain.

Comment: Then maybe I just choose the one with which the Statement maybe works. :-)

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts In the tutorial it was just said that the Statement follows by the fact that if $L^{-1}$ exists and is bounded, the compactness follows by the compact embedding. To be honest, I did not understand that and in fact, this seems too easy to me. Maybe you can give me a hint?

Comment: I think the only way to interpret this to get compactness of the resolvent is to assume that $\|T^{-1}f\|_{H^2} \le C\|f\|_{L^2}$. That would do it because $T^{-1}$ would map a bounded subset in $L^2$ into a bounded subset in $H^2$, which would be compact in $L^2$. So I'd say that's how it must be interpreted in order to get the desired result.